# Multiplying floats in python

Tags: python

in my python code I search for a specific format which then returns floats ie

```
...
        return {'ID': int(dataINgood[0]),
                'mIdx': int(dataINgood[2])-1,
                'Px' : float(dataINgood[6]),
                'Py' : float(dataINgood[7]),
                'Pz' : float(dataINgood[8]),
                'E' : float(dataINgood[9]),
                'M' : float(dataINgood[10])}
```

What I want is to do something line

```
'Pt' : math.sqrt(float( dataINgood[6] * dataINgood[6]) + float(dataINgood[7]*dataINgood[7]))
```

but this returns

```
'Pt' : math.sqrt(float( dataINgood[6] * dataINgood[6]) + float(dataINgood[7]*dataINgood[7])) }
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Any hint ?

thanks

Comment: dataINgood is a list of string ?

Comment: I don't think this is a pretty or pythonic way of doing this.  

Why use a dict?  Make a class (an inner class if you like).  Add an initializer.  In the initializer set the self.sqrt = math.sqrt(self.Px\*\*2 + self.Py\*\*2).  It'll be easier to read and you won't get the kind of problem you've just had.

Comment: Since when classes are "more pythonic"? Nevertheless class fit better since the keys are "known at compile time" so IDEs can help. I'd suggest using namedtuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `dataINgood` is a `list` of `strings`. You need to convert the values to `float`:

```
'Pt' : math.sqrt(float( dataINgood[6] ) * float( dataINgood[6]) + 
       float(dataINgood[7]) * float(dataINgood[7]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast everything, then work:

```
fs = [float(x) for x in dataINgood]
{... 'Pt' : math.sqrt(fs[6]**2 + fs[7]**2) }
```

BTW, this is better:

```
{... 'Pt' : math.hypot(fs[6], fs[7]) }
```

So your code looks like this:

```
fs = [float(x) for x in dataINgood]
return {'ID': int(fs[0]),
        'mIdx': int(fs[2])-1,
        'Px' : fs[6],
        'Py' : fs[7],
        'Pz' : fs[8],
        'E' : fs[9],
        'M' : fs[10],
        'Pt' : math.hypot(fs[6], fs[7])
        }
```

Comment: Good use of `hypot`. The conversion to float and back to int for `dataINgood[0]` and `dataINgood[2]` seems weird though. Maybe something like `fs = [float(x) for x in dataIngood[6:11]]` is better?

Comment: Weird, but why not? The correctness depends on whether the rest of `dataINgood` is also "floatable" of course. If it is not guaranteed, your suggestion is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
math.sqrt(float( dataINgood[6] * dataINgood[6]) + float(dataINgood[7]*dataINgood[7]))
```

you need to convert dataINgood[x] to float before multiplication so you should try below syntax

```
**math.sqrt((float(dataINgood[6]) * float(dataINgood[6])) + (float(dataINgood[7])* float(dataINgood[7])))**
```